# Thicken edges of a polyhedron

Tags: edges

I have basics polyhedrons like tetrahedrons and I would like to thicken their edges to make them seem like in this picture but with soft rounded edge instead of spheres.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Skin* modifier, it will give thickness to all your edges (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to thicken in *Edit* mode):

[image]

Here is the result once you apply it:

[image]

You'll probably need to rework on some parts of the topology:

[image]

Corner corrected:

[image]

If you apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with a level of 1:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All work like you sayd exepted that my egdes are to thick and I don't find an option in modifiers to adjust it

Comment: You need to go in Edit mode, select all, press Ctrl A and drag

Comment: It work. Thank you.